# recaptcha server side integration

Tags: recaptcha

i'm trying to add recaptcha to an existing contact form.
i have done step 1 (client side integration) on google
but i don't understand step2
the directions for server side say:

send a POST request with these parameters:

URL: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify
secret (required)   6LfWAFAUAAAAALhRhjHZ1OdoMexS50EqSuxoF5jq
response (required) The value of 'g-recaptcha-response'.
remoteip    The end user's ip address.

i have my own secret key but how do i "send a POST"?

if anyone has the patience to explain this whole step, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

When user deals with re-captcha, re-captcha response is appended into the relevant div by google code. You wouldn't need to worry about it.

What you need to do is to ensure **if it is there and valid.**

For my case, I use [jqBootstrapValidation](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) to help validating my form components.

```
$("#myElement").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
         // do something useful for error case
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        // ...
        var g_captcha_response = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
        // if response does not exist, do NOT proceed
        if (!(g_captcha_response && g_captcha_response.length>0)){
           return;
        }
        // User is HUMAN. So charge ahead.!
        ...
```

**EDIT**

I use [recaptcha-V2](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) for my site.

Comment: thanks. the code above goes on the contact form and that's it?

Comment: I used above code snippet in a "contact us" page, in which I validated user input. Once everything is OK, I sent an email to site admin. In above code, I redirected flow onto a server side, where there is a positive re-captcha response, in order to send that email. And yes, that's all. If this worked for you, please accept my answer. Cheers.

Comment: i'm clearly missing some stuff. i pasted the code above into my form page but it doesn't work. i think in the google documentation and maybe in your case, obvious stuff is left out of the explanation. thanks for your response. i don't know backend languages and so i may be asking too much.

Comment: I am sure you have already checked out the example https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display. However, it would not hurt to re-visit that page. In that sample code, verifyCallback method for the 3rd widget is where you want to do something.